# Entity Framework permissions issue

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I work for a government client and they are extremely strict about security. Unfortunately this means that our developers are not allowed to have permanent local admin for our machines. If we need admin access we can request it for the day but it becomes tiresome always having to request this. I recently ran into a problem because of this. I set up a new solution with Entity Framework and got local admin for the day just in case I would need it. So I set up my solution and ran Install-Package EntityFramework via the package manager console and everything seems fine.

When I came back in the next morning (no longer having local admin rights) I get the following error when I load my solution and open the package manager console.

```
& : The term 'C:\Users\KAMENARN\source\repos\CodeFirstExample\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\init.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:45
+ ... rgs+=$_}; & 'C:\Users\KAMENARN\source\repos\CodeFirstExample\packages ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\KAMENA...\tools\init.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

As a result of this none of the commands for EF (like Add-Migration or Update-Database) are available. If I request local admin again and open the solution everything works. Is there a way I can enable and use these commands without needing local admin?

Comment: Which Visual Studio and NuGet version do you have? Are you sure that the files are present on hard drive?

Comment: VS 2017 v15.4.2 and nuget v4.4.0
Yes the files are there and everything works if I run VS as admin, the problem is without admin rights I don't have permission to run the init.ps1 EF script when the project loads so I don't have access to the commands.

Answer (score 0):

In past I've got some issues with executing EF commands in PMC, following solved it:

Try to re-install the EntityFramework packag in PMC (`Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease`) or via NuGet Package Manager and restart VS.

In past it solves the issue for me.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I've misunderstood your question.
You could try to execute `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` in PowerShell.

Another approach would be to disable all extensions you have installed. Maybe one will cause your the issue.

Comment: No luck, I get basically the same error message during install if I don't have admin rights. The problem seems to be that there is an install.ps1 script and an init.ps1 script that EF uses and our policies here don't allow me to run these powershell scripts unless I have admin rights. I was wondering if there is a way to manually run a command to enable the EF cmdlets in place of the init.ps1 script.

Comment: Already tried setting the execution policy too and it had no effect even after restarting VS. I think it may be getting overridden by a group policy so I need a way of enabling the commands without running the init script.

Comment: Do you have full access to your file system where your NuGet packages (*.ps1 path from your question - `C:\Users\KAMENARN\source\repos`) are located? As far as I know no admin privileges are needed to use EF (or other packages) in PMC.

Comment: Yup I have full control, I think it is most likely caused by a group policy enforced on our network that only allows admins to run powershell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It almost a year now, but just in case this might help someone, you should check if your company's IT department uses AVECTO Privilege Guard/DefendPoint or similar privilege management system which can be used to temporarily grant program-limited admin privileges for development purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we had to place our projects only within the following location, C:\Users(user.name)\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects
--If the "Projects" folder didn't exist, it had to be created. We think this worked for us because of a rule/policy within McAfee itself.